# Option to be notified when any message is posted in a chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

Is there a way to be notified when *any* message is posted in a chat room? I participate in a couple of chat rooms with few participants in which every message is interesting to me. One of them is a private chat for the three moderators of UX.SE. We'd each like the other two to be notified whenever we post a message, but I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: A manual way would to always include the other two mods @ names in the first message you post. A bit clunky, but it would work.

Comment: @ChrisF Does that actually work, though? I thought only the first \@mention was notified?

Comment: In chat, multiple mentions will work. On Gaming, when there's important discussion matters in our room, we always ping everyone at the start.

Answer (score 5):

If all you need is an alert in the form of a sound, then there is a setting that gets you most of the way there, if not all the way. In the top right of the room window, there is a sound icon which allows you to configure the sound settings between `none`, `when mentioned`, `visible room`, `all rooms`. The lattermost will cause sound alerts in any rooms that you are idling in (simply leave yourself logged in without `leaving`) whenever anyone posts a message. It may be wise to use headphones.

I think a case could be made for a narrower option that lets you specify which rooms, if for example one had to monitor a handful of small rooms but was also in a very active room.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's kind of like a cell phone that only rings once, is attached to my desk, and doesn't have a missed call notification. But this definitely gets me some of the way there. :)

Comment: I had some thoughts about the global inbox regarding viability (you can check it in the [source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/d944e3b8-e598-4ff4-86ed-f9c0a7a0cb08/view-source) of my answer), but ultimately withdrew it because that seemed to be too tangential.

Comment: The biggest advantage of having a global inbox notification is I wouldn't have to keep the chat window open (or keep looking at it).